# Trying to get Rust to load files

Tags: file, rust

I'm having trouble trying to get Rust to load files in subdirectories. Rust treats the files as the modules and the code as part of the module, but I'm used to Ruby's way of treating files and directories separate from the code that they contain.

**src/main.rs**

```
mod lib {
    pub mod manifest;
}
```

**src/lib/manifest.rs**

```
mod structs {
    pub mod entity;
}
```

**src/lib/structs/entity.rs**

```
pub struct entity {
    type: String
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error: cannot declare a new module at this location
 --> src/lib/manifest.rs:2:13
  |
2 |     pub mod entity;
  |             ^^^^^^
  |
note: maybe move this module `structs` to its own directory via `structs/mod.rs`
 --> src/lib/manifest.rs:2:13
  |
2 |     pub mod entity;
  |             ^^^^^^
note: ... or maybe `use` the module `entity` instead of possibly redeclaring it
 --> src/lib/manifest.rs:2:13
  |
2 |     pub mod entity;
  |             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Have you read [the book chapter on modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/crates-and-modules.html)? If you explain what issues you have with the explanation from the book, we might be able to help. Otherwise, we will most likely just repeat what the book says.

Comment: You could also check out the [revised book-in-progress](http://rust-lang.github.io/book/ch07-00-modules.html) to see if that way of explaining is better suited.

Comment: Thanks, was helpful, the second link I mean.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the error message's note? What other things have you tried? What are you actually trying to do, why do you want to structure your project in the way that you're trying to? A better title that's in the form of a question might also help people to understand the problem better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to fix this is to rename the manifest file to **mod.rs** and change the first line in **main.rs** to:

```
mod lib;
```

and change **mod.rs** to:

```
pub mod structs {
    mod entity;
}
```

I think the reason for your error is because there's a **manifest.rs** file but no folder. Why this causes the subfolder files to not load I can't say, I'm still new to Rust myself so there's a good chance I'm wrong.

Someone with more Rust knowledge might know, but since they're downvoting instead of being helpful, I doubt you'd get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, thing is someone did comment on the question with a link to some information about modules which was helpful and in the end I already made those changes you mentioned and it did indeed make the error go away but thanks for trying any way. I also partially agree,I think because there's no folder it breaks the loadtree and rust doesn't like it so it just screams "Nope, can\'t new module here as there is no subfolder" or somthing like that, but since no one is trying to simply, I don't really know.

Comment: May I ask why you are answering the question and then commenting on your own answer as if there are multiple people involved? Perhaps you meant to log into separate accounts for some reason?

Comment: Wow, I guess it went over your head huh. You were helpful so I'm grateful, My answer was me pretending to be someone trying to answer the question and me commenting was me pretending to be me commenting on someone answering me.