# Unresolved import when organising Rust code in multiple directories

Tags: rust

I am used to organising files in separate directories depending on the problem domain (for example grouping image processing stuff together, IO stuff in another directory etc). I am not sure if this way or organisation is even recommended in Rust.

I have setup my project in multiple directories:

```
- helloworld
    - Cargo.toml
    - src
        - main.rs
        - test
            - one.rs
```

I am trying to use a function from `one.rs` in `main.rs`

**one.rs**

```
fn test() {
    println!("Calling test...");
}
```

**main.rs**

```
use test::one::*;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    test();
}
```

This results in a compile time error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `test::one::*`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use test::one::*;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Maybe a missing `extern crate test;`?

error[E0425]: cannot find function `test` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     test();
  |     ^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Looking at some online projects, it seems like something like this should be possible.

Comment: Please take the time to read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/). It has an [entire section on how modules live on the filesystem](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch07-01-mod-and-the-filesystem.html).

Comment: Have you read [the "Modules" chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch07-00-modules.html)? I'd really recommend you to read all of it to understand the whole module system. The tl;dr is: you need `mod` declarations. [See here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43262123/2408867). And if interested: this might change in the future -- there is a lot of discussion about how to redesign Rust's modules.

Comment: Thank you for these pointers. I just started using it and looking at the online book. Was just jumping a bit ahead there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, however you need to inform your code about additional module that is inside your code using:

```
mod test;
```

And then create additional file

```
// src/test/mod.rs

pub mod one;
```